# Java2Word export, format Table Cells individually

Tags: java, java2word

I have a Database agent that generates a word document from IBM Notes data. I am using the Java2Word API to achieve this but unfortunately, this API has little Documentation and I couldn't find anything regarding table formatting (size, merging, etc.).

Here are my methods for row generating:
     `

```
public void AddFirstRow(String[] Items){
                    CurrentTable.addTableEle(TableEle.TH, Items);
            }
            public void AddRow(String[] items){
                    CurrentTable.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, items);
            }
            public void AddLastRow(String[] items){
                    CurrentTable.addTableEle(TableEle.TD, items);
            }
```

`

Does anyone have prior experience using this library and knows how to implement table formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone will try this ever again, this is not possible by using default methods of Java2Word, I created my own oXML template in the proper format and added it to the Jar.